# Is PowerShell part of Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell

Not sure if Powershell is a part of Window 2008 Server? I cannot find it from cmd console. Just to avoid to download it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed bundled with Server 2008, although it needs to be installed using the method you mentioned. Note that this is version 1.0 of PowerShell, 2.0 is now available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/968929) (see bottom of page).

Comment: PowerGUID is another great tool, but I think I have to download it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I find out the solution. From Server Manager->Features, there is one for "Windows PowerShell". It is unchecked by default.